# How to create a table which contains all table names in a database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a table which contains all table names in a database using the stored procedure. I have to done this without using Information schema. I've tried lot of methods using `show tables from <dbname>` in my stored procedure but everything fails. I've also tried to use prepare statement which also not working.
please anyone help me on this scenario to achieve my task

Comment: Try: `select table_name from information_schema.tables;`   see: [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html))

Comment: There is no need to create a stored procedure for that, I would create a VIEW if you want a slight change of that **existing** table.

Comment: But I need to create the table without using information_schema

Comment: Sorry did overlook that, but why do you need to do it without using information_schema?  The whole point of the existence of `information_schema` is to be informational, so why not use it ?

Comment: *I need to create the table without using information_schema* Why? Alternative solution is not safe - you'd need to retrieve the data from `mysql.schemata` and `mysql.tables`, but none users have access privileges to these tables.

Comment: When you want/need to create a stored procedure using `show tables from <dbname>`, you should provide the code your created so far, and explain where your problem is.

Comment: my task is to create a table name list in a table without using information_schema

Comment: @Luuk OP wants "to create a table which contains all table names in a database using the stored procedure". SHOW statement cannot be datasource on MySQL side, only outer client may use its output as a rowset.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You need to explain _WHY_ you need to avoid using information_schema. I don't think anyone answering this question can understand what solution you need unless you explain this reason.

Comment: You may want to know that commands like `SHOW TABLES` (and many other SHOW commands) are internal aliases for queries against the information_schema. So even if you could capture the result of a SHOW command, you aren't actually doing it without using the information_schema.

Answer (score 0):

First to create a new table that can store the names of all tables:

```
CREATE TABLE all_tables_name (
    table_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Then add all the names of the table:

```
INSERT INTO all_tables_name
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

'all_tables_name' will have the names of all tables

**note:** 'all_tables_name' will also have one row with the table itself 'all_tables_name'.

Comment: is there any alternate way to create tables list without using information_schema?